# Is there a way to use the PostgreSQL ANY operator on a column to perform operations on an array field in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am trying to use the npgsql provider in EF Core to get all array fields that have at least one item satisfy a certain condition (greater than, less than etc). But the SQL statement generated is always doing an Array contains statement of the PostgreSQL.

For example when I try to do a query using the below syntax

```cs
var result = (from i in _dbContext.Set<Image>()
              where i.PixelSpacing != null && i.PixelSpacing.Any(ps => ps >= 0.5)
              select i.ImageId).ToList();
```

I am expecting that the corresponding SQL statement in the PostgreSQL to be something like where

```
WHERE 0.5 < ANY(pixel_spacing)
```

but the statement filter executed is

```
WHERE pixel_spacing @> ARRAY[0.5]::double precision[]
```

Is what I am trying to do achievable using EF Core and npgsql in some other way, or am I missing something?

The executed statement:

```sql
SELECT i.image_id
FROM image AS i
WHERE ((i.pixel_spacing IS NOT NULL)) 
  AND i.pixel_spacing @> ARRAY[0.5]::double precision[]
```

`PixelSpacing` is of type `double[]`

Comment: Paste code instead of images.

Comment: Updated the question with the code @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: Looking at documentation of [Array Type Mapping](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html) and I do not see possibility to do that.

Comment: Ok. I was guessing that might be the case too. Thanks for the response. Will see if there are ways around it